# Redis to Go - Heroku - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I'm trying to get [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) playing in Heroku. Without Luck.. My configs look like that:

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT --max-pool-size 5
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

Initializers/redis.rb

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/")
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])
```

but when i do `heroku ps` only the web instance is shown. Not Sidekiq.

However i can manually run `heroku run sidekiq` and run my workers. What am i missing so that Heroku doesn't start that on it's own ?

Comment: Is there anything in your Heroku logs?

Comment: Have you added a worker dyno?  `heroku ps:scale worker=1`

Comment: I tweaked around and by manually starting Redis once it now stays connected and everything works. Will try to reproduce the error and Edit my Question. As for the logs: - Connection Refused and Bad URI (not URI?) -. As for the Worker: Yes i have an active worker.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't configure Sidekiq in the initializer so that Sidekiq knows exactly how to connect to redis. Create Initializers/sidekiq.rb and add the following code

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { :url => ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] }
end
```

Also you can remove

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/")
```

You don't need it as you are using the redis url from the environment.
Don't forget to restart your server.